# Akamai CDN - Whitelist service by Request header or User agent

Tags: akamai

We are using Akamai CDN as our load balancer and it also servers as a gatekeeper for requests.
We usually consume 3rd party services and in those cases whitelist their IP to be accessed in our servers.  The service we are currently using cannot share IP since it is on cloud and keeps changing. They can either provide host name or Custom request header or a user agent.

I tried adding host entry but that did not work. Any idea how to add custom request header or user agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the product you're using to deliver with Akamai, the solution is to add a "Modify Outgoing Request Header" behavior.

This is what the "Add Behavior" tool looks like when you filter behaviors on "header".

> [image: Screenshot of Akamai Property Manager's Add Behavior tool]

By default, this allows you to specify a User-Agent header to go to your origin with the request. You can also specify a custom header name and value using that Behavior.

If you make it part of your Default Rule, then every single request that goes through that property will have the custom header.

Comment: thanks @josh - forgot about this question since this was asked long time back.. i ended up doing the exact same thing you mentioned..